# working on an automation to approve the Pull Request from Logic App Flow

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automation, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I am working on automating the approval process of a Pull request(in Azure DevOps) using Logic app.
I have already built the flow with few conditions to meet and then the flow has to approve the PR automatically if the conditions are met.

Need suggestion on which action/trigger will approve the Pull request automatically?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe look at using the relevant REST API ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/update

You can see there are a couple of fields in the payload you'll need to pay attention to, `vote` being one of them and `status` being the other.

You'll need to authenticate and to do that, it'll be a matter of picking one of the auth methods listed here ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops

PAT is typically the easiest but be sure to restrict it's access in case the key is compromised.

Now having said that, there is a very specific section on auth which you'll need to make sure you adhere to.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0#security

Comment: This helped with the implementation. Thank You @Skin